# How to fill an object with entity framework and stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

Assume I have a database with a table "Order" and a table "Items" where "Order" can have many "Items".  In code I have a POCO that looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string MoreOrderInfo { get; set; }

    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF6, how do I create a stored procedure that will return the Orders and the Items sub to each order that I can then use to populate my Order and its Items?  Maybe the trick isn't in the stored procedure. Maybe the trick is in the configuration of EF.

I understand that this functionality comes by default when EF is used to connect to the database directly but I need to understand how to do it using stored procedures.

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
public List<Order> GetOrders()
{
    using(var db = new Context())
    {
        var orders = new List<Order>();
        foreach(var order in db.GetOrders())
        {
            order.Items = db.GetItems(int order.OrderId);
            orders.Add(order);
        }
        return orders;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Comment: You already have a code that works. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @RogerWolf, It just doesn't seem like the best solution.  I am making two calls to the database and to two separate stored procedures.  It doesn't seem like a good solution for all cases especially one where new records could be entered between stored procedure calls.  It would be best, IMO, to do one call that gets it all.

Comment: You will have to access 2 objects in the database anyway, either from your app or from stored proc - there is no magic in wrapping them into sp. The "new rows" problem is unavoidable, unless you either switch to some very restrictive isolation levels or cache the first set and then use it as a filter condition (and here sp can help, yes, but do you actually need it?). Personally, I prefer to first load all master rows, and then all child rows for them - seems to be best bang for the buck. Especially considering how "easy" it is to use procedures from EF.